# How to use dynamic parameter in custom rest api module?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

Here is the url I want to to access the custom rest api.

`http://127.0.0.1/index.php/rest/V1/customapi/filter1/sku_gt_2/filter2/price_gt_10`

How do I define webapi.xml & the method parameters in interface?

```
<route url="/V1/customapi/add/:^filter/:value" method="GET">
    <service class="Custom\Pluginname\Api\CustomInterface" method="add"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

interface:

```
public function add($filter, $value);
```

Is the about parameter filter can be received as a array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use array, but you can use mixed as a Valid scalar type

for your example  try to use this

in your **webapi.xml** file use this url [**/V1/customapi/add**]

your interface

```
    /**
     * @param mixed $filter
     * @return string
     */
    public function add($filter);
```

put your return type as you need

you model could be

```
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function add($filter)
    {
        return $filter['1'].$filter['2'];
    }
```

use the array as you need

end point example

```
/V1/customapi/add?filter[1]=sku_gt_2&filter[2]=price_gt_10
```

See

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html

for more details
Hope this will help you